# Can android app widgets support full screen and webview?

Tags: android, widget

I want to create a app widget in my desktop and let it support full screen and webview, but I can't find any solution [Click Here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

So I am wondering whether there is a way to let app widget support full screen and webview?Or it's designed to not support such function?

**I don't think it worth any down vote , in a company , do my best to meet product's requirements should be down vote????** I know it's a very strange question , but I just need others to tell me I can't do this not because I don't have enough skill！Even the official documentation tell me it's almost impossible , but I still ask in Stack Overflow, I don't want to give it up so quick.

Comment: when you say full screen widgets? Are you still talking about android app widgets???? Or a view widget? Actually, have you ever seen a full screen app widget? I'd love to see one :)

Comment: @Leo Yes , it's very strange , but as a developer , I should do my best to meet the requirements.

Comment: good on ya, mate. Whoever put the requirements together is obviously not a developer :)

Comment: @Leo absolutely they are not.

Comment: that edit in bold text is like asking for more downvotes...just saying :)

Comment: @Leo Let them down more , I don't care any. I think my question have no problem.

Comment: Widget has to be placed on launcher and therefore cannot be full screen. If you absolutely need one, implementing your own launcher that can add full screen widget to it may works (I haven't tried this).

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Many thanks , and it can support webview ?

Comment: @zzy Unfortunately, widget does not support webview in any case [according to it's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I have read it already , thanks for your help , please post your answer and I will accept it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget has to be placed on launcher and therefore cannot be full screen. If you absolutely need one, implementing your own launcher that can add full screen widget to it may works (I haven't tried this). You probably cannot hide notification bar with it though.

Unfortunately, widget does not support webview [according to the documation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)